# How to read from a text file and split it into values in C++

Tags: c++

This is my text file (`mytext.text`):

```
rho_0,10
kp_0,8
Beta_kp,6
x_min,5
x_max,8
y_min,9
y_max,5
z_min,4
z_max,7
```

I want to read from this text file line by line, and store each value in the parameter at the same line.

For example, for the first line, store `10` in `rho_0`.

I have written this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main ()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("mytext.txt");
    
    if (myfile.is_open())
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }    
    }
```

But I don't think it will save the value for the corresponding parameter.

I know that I should split each line by delimiter, and then convert string to `double` (`float`), but I don't know how to implement it for each line.

Comment: [Use option 2 of this linked answer as a base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301). Where it uses `>>` to split up the line, you want another `getline`, specifically something like `getline(iss, token, ',')` to split on the comma. To convert `token` from a `std::string` to a double, [use `std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: You;; probably want to use a map data structure in order to store the values: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

You can't dynamically declare new names for variables so you need to store your values in some kind of container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a map data structure of some sort to store parameter values. You'll probably want `std::unordered_map` for this. Like @user4581301 said, you can use `std::getline` with a specific delimiter, like a comma.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, float> params;
std::ifstream myfile("mytext.txt");
std::string param_name;
float param_value;
while (std::getline(myfile, param_name, ',')) {
    myfile >> param_value;
    myfile.get(); // discard newline
    params.insert({ param_name, param_value });
}
```

This code doesn't handle invalid input, so you can add error handling if you want.

Comment: I would suggest using `myfile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` instead of `myfile.get()`.  Alternatively, don't use `','` on the outer `getline()` at all, and then use `istringstream` to parse each line inside the loop, eg: `while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
istringstream iss(line); getline(iss, param_name, ','); iss >> param_value; params.insert({ param_name, param_value }); }`